# Share cookie between subdomain and subsubdomain

Tags: http, cookies, browser, http-headers

I was reading the answer of this questions here: [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

It does not answer one of my question what if we want to push it one level further by having a sub2.sub1.domain.com

Can an application hosted on sub2.sub1.domain.com set a cookie on .sub1.domain.com ?

and then would this cooke be available for an application on sub1.domain.com and not available on an application on sub3.domain.com?

If so is that supported by all the browsers? I am trying to find the RFC specification that would either show that this is possible or impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Just came across something like this and I was able to set a cookie from sub2.sub1.domain.com to .sub1.domain.com. The cookie wasn't made available on other subdomains (sub3.domain.com).

I couldn't find any specific specification however this seems to work on the latest version of Firefox (53.0) and chrome (57.0)

Comment: This is not an answer. If you need help on this topic, you can post a new question, include a link to this post, clearly state why your question is not a duplicate of this question and why the answers here do not solve your problem.